# Ember-cli how to change input path of files

Tags: ember.js, compilation, ember-cli

I am new to ember. But for a particular task i need to change input path of templates to compile. i.e default is app/templates. but i want to change this path. 
I have read the ember-cli-build.js file but i can edit only output path. how can i edit the input path.
My ember-cli-build.js

```
var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');

module.exports = function(defaults) {
  var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
    // Add options here
    outputPaths: {
      app: {
        html: 'ember_build_index.html'
      }
    }
  });

  // Use `app.import` to add additional libraries to the generated
  // output files.
  //
  // If you need to use different assets in different
  // environments, specify an object as the first parameter. That
  // object's keys should be the environment name and the values
  // should be the asset to use in that environment.
  //
  // If the library that you are including contains AMD or ES6
  // modules that you would like to import into your application
  // please specify an object with the list of modules as keys
  // along with the exports of each module as its value.

app.import('bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js');
app.import('bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css');
app.import('bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css.map');
  return app.toTree();
};
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You can use an in-repo addon, but depending what you want you also need to edit your resolver.

Comment: because i want to use different templates for mobiles with little modifications from web. but want to keep javascript same.

Comment: Extend from your existing components, and just set `layoutName` in your new component with the name of the mobile template

Comment: Is that possible to change the base templates  path anyhow?? at the time of compilation.

Comment: This is not a good idea. If you want your app to work on mobile and web, write a responsive layout. You don't want the hassle of keeping two templates in sync. What happens when you start building components and helpers? It's just not a road that leads to happiness. :)

Comment: I have my web app running with all the templates defined under 'app/templates'. Now, I want to keep the javascript files the same and create new templates with same names in some other directory e.g, 'app/templates/mobile'.
So, how can i specify something like
 templates:{root: <path>} as I do using brunch compiler with previous ember versions ( < 1.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change templates directory path for the ember app being built.

To check your current templates directory path, check app.trees.templates._directoryPath in your ember-cli-build.js by log it to console using console.log(app.trees.templates._directoryPath) .

Now, if you want your ember build to have templates from 'app/templates/mobile' (in your case), just change:
app.trees.templates._directoryPath = 'app/templates/mobile' in ember-cli-build.js before it returns app.toTree();

The node_module which constructs tree for templates is at 'node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js' at line no. 724 where it accesses 'this.trees.templates' in which this is the instance of your app.